# Why can't I read a file with permissions applied on it?

Tags: unix

On, Unix system, I do the following:

```
sudo su
mkdir test
touch test/x.txt
chmod -R 700 test
exit
```

Right now, the whole `test` folder is protected for only `root` user usage.

Now, I do

```
sudo su
chmod 777 test/x.txt
exit
```

Then, in a "normal" user, I do

```
cat test/x.txt
```

But I get `permission denied`, although file `test/x.txt` is open to world.
why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was the "normal" user cannot cd into `test` - because missing `x` permissions.

So instead of doing `chmod -R 700 test`, replace with something like `chmod -R 711 test`